# I wanna develop a real time graph app but It doesn't work

Tags: android

this is the code It runs on emulator but it doesn't give real time values

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GraphView graph1 = (GraphView)findViewById(R.id.main_graph1);

    Series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    graph1.addSeries(Series);
```

Here I go to simulate real time with thread that append data:

```
 protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            for(int i = 0; i<100; i++);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    addEntry();
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(600);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    });
}
```

I think it seems to be wrong please help

Comment: you forgot to call `start` and `;` after for

Comment: I didn't get it. can you clarify what you said please?

Answer (score 0):

Issues :

1.) A thread will only be executed when you invoke `start` function on your thread object (which is missing)

2.) `for(int i = 0; i<100; i++);` this loop won't do anything due to terminated body by `;` at the end

so solution would be

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) // ; removed 
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                addEntry();
            }
        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start(); // invoke start for execution
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked, now It shows real time values

Comment: i am glad that i could help